# Why does Prestashop does not replace http links by https on front-office?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have activated and deactivated all the SSL options several times:

[image]

But when I inspect the code, all the links are always **http** and not **https**. This problem only appeared this morning and the [site](https://www.ineselah.com) was running well until then.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: This is not a Prestashop error, your certificate appears to be expired today,
you'll need to renew it.

Comment: I understand, but can it be that the certificate expirated because some unproper code or manipulation was done on the website ? or on the server's website ? thank you